# Can I use Node.js into my windows phone 8 application?

Tags: html, node.js, sockets, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app which requires transfer of data over socket. I have to use standard http protocol to send and receive data over sockets. So can I use Node.js into my windows phone 8 application for creating and parsing Http Requests and responses respectively?

I am writing code in c# .NET.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vijay

Comment: This is confusing. What do you want? Are you tryin to install node on your phone or on the server? Please make your question clearer..

Comment: I have created the application and i am able to send and receive data over sockets using c#. I have created a basic html parser also, but the problem is,,, its not standard. Creating a perfect html parser is itself a big project. So, I was thinking of using some library like node.js to save my effort

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot create Windows Phone applications using HTML5+JavaScript, so you won't be able to use this library in your app.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940(v=vs.105).aspx

> HTML-based phone apps aren’t a supported app model in Windows Phone 8.
>   However, a developer can create a managed app with a XAML front end
>   that uses an embedded browser control to display local HTML content,
>   and it’s possible to access phone APIs by using the InvokeScript
>   method and ScriptNotify events. Also, in Windows Phone 8, the phone’s
>   browser has been upgraded to Internet Explorer Mobile 10, with a host
>   of new features such as a robust HTML5/CSS3 implementation, Scalable
>   Vector Graphics (SVG), ES5, IndexedDB, gesture events, and the
>   addition of the high-performance scripting engine, creating new,
>   interesting possibilities for Windows Phone 8 HTML developers.

But if you just want to use sockets in your WIndows Phone app, you can use them directly in C#:
[Sockets for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I have created the application and i am able to send and receive data over sockets using c#. I have created a basic html parser also, but the problem is,,, its not standard. Creating a perfect html server is itself a big project. So, I was thinking of using some library like node.js to save my effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about node.js but if your goal is to serve static files, such as html, you could look into the Katana Project here: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/releases/view/113281

As for dynamic data on your static files you could leverage Owin and self host a SignalR endpoint on the phone: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

With SignalR, and C# you could expose much of the phone's functionality and sensor data on your phone.

To avoid creating a lot of unneeded boilerplate code, you could bind the data to your static html with mv* frameworks such as KnockoutJs or AngularJs. For cool looking graphs, you could leverage D3.js